# Convert a column in Gridview into Template field in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which is populated from the database through a query in C# code. The requirement is to make a column invisible and another column as a link button. I managed to make the column invisible and make other column as link button. I used the following code:

```
protected void dgvArticles_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
    var titleCell = e.Row.Cells[5];
    titleCell.Controls.Clear();
    titleCell.Controls.Add(new LinkButton { Text = titleCell.Text, CommandName = "link", CommandArgument = e.Row.Cells[0].ToString() });
}
```

The Grid is as expected, but when I click the link button the link gets disabled. Also the code inside the RowCommand doesn't work on click of the link button field.

GridView MarkUp:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvArticles" runat="server" 
    onrowcommand="dgvArticles_RowCommand" onrowdatabound="dgvArticles_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCFFFF" ForeColor="#996600" />
    <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Medium" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Is there a way, I can convert bound field to template field through C# code. I googled, but couldn't find any working solution. Any link/procedure on what can be done will be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: The reason why the RowCommand is not working is  that controls need to be added to the page during the PreInit event, RowBound is too late. You are better off making the column a template column in mark up ad a label and link and adjust their visibility accordingly. As for changing to a template field programmatically, I don't see this working, for  a start thin about how you would define the template.

Comment: I am populating the GridView through a SQL query in C# back end code. Is it possible to access template fields of GridView in back end code ?

Comment: And any idea how to sustain the link on post back ?

Comment: Yes you can access controls in a template field on RowBoundm, you need to use `FindControl()`. Also look into [DataKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of hiding a column if all you are doing is using it's data. Perhaps describe what you are trying to achieve here instead of how you are trying to achieve it. Sorry I haven't got time to give you a fully fledged answer at the moment.

Comment: That's fine. I will try a little more based on what you said, if I couldn't get it, will elaborate a little more. Thanks a lot for your time !!

Comment: Also are you auto generating columns? Do you need to? Perhaps include your GridView Markup in the question.

Comment: I added. There isn't much I do in mark up. I get values in a query and bind it to gridview in code.

Comment: @Partha Why *not* define your columns in markup as Jon suggested? Then you wouldn't be fighting against the page/control lifecycle.

Comment: Actually this is new requirement. This is existing code where I am asked to change a column to link button. Ya maybe I will change the mark up and use FindControl() as suggested by @JonP.

Comment: While you're looking at requirements take the time to see/ask if you need to AutoGenerate columns, I think in 10 years I have deployed less than 5 data grids using auto generated columns.

Comment: @JonP Auto generated columns using Dynamic Data is crazy awesome. We've used it before and I highly recommend the approach to whoever uses Web Forms. It's one of the things I miss the most after started working with MVC and knockout. Without dynamic data though, yeah, they are pretty useless since you have too little control over them.

Comment: Thanks all. I implemented the above solution suggested by @JonP. If you wish, you can add that as an answer and I will be happy to accept it :)

Comment: Thanks Partha, I just gave direction, not an answer, what would be more helpful for future users is you post what you did as an answer and accept that . It would be a more complete answer than my suggestions.